# How to calculate the variance using least square method if the regression line is vertical to x-axis

Tags: curve-fitting, curve, least-squares

I have some data in a 2D plane. I want to calculate their variance but the regression line could be vertical to x-axis, what's the proper way to obtain the variance?

Comment: Try have a look at Michael Krystek and Mathias Anton Meas. Sci. Technol. 18 (2007) 3438–3442

Comment: Why don't you try to calculate R square as 1 - SSres / SStot

Answer (score 0):

If you are fitting a line to data but are okay with it being vertical, this looks less like linear regression (which assumes y is a function of x) and more like [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  Which can be done with sklearn as follows, computing the variance along the way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data = np.random.multivariate_normal([1, 1], [[0.2, 0], [0, 4]], size=100)
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(data)
print('Residual variance', pca.explained_variance_[1])
```

I fit two components here, which together explain all the variance since the data is 2D. The first component is the line that takes place of the regression line in this model. The second is where the residuals are, so the residual variance comes from there. Visualization:

```
line_direction = pca.components_[0]
M = np.abs(data).max()
t = np.linspace(-M, M)
center = data.mean(axis=0)
line = line_direction*t[:, None] + center
plt.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], 'r')
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], '.')
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

The simulated data is random, but this is what it can look like:

[image: pca]

> Residual variance 0.23184791439896069

This is the variance in the direction perpendicular to the chosen line, not in the vertical direction (which wouldn't be appropriate here).

Related: [Total least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares)